# Autocomplete for unknown properties

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

Is it possible to PhpStorm to autocomplete unknown properties?
Here is sample code:

```
class Fields {
    public function __construct($data) {
        foreach ($data AS $d) {
            $propName=$d['id'];
            $this->$propName=$d['value'];
        }
    }
}

$data=[
    ['id'=>'myId', 'value'=>'Name'],
    ['id'=>'second', 'value'=>'Second]
];

$fields=new Fields($data);

$fields->second;//comes from autocpmplete
```

I want 'second' or 'myId' property to be autocompleted. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to have it absolute dynamic (e.g. the same `Fields` class but in one file `$fields` variable will have one set of fields and in another completely different) -- then no (unless you will have separate class every time -- see next). Other than that -- it's possible to declare non-existing property via `@property` tag (https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#714-property) in PHPDoc comment for that class, e.g. `/** @property string $abc */ class Fields { ...` -- now every instance of `Fields` will have `abc` property in completion

Comment: Thanks for response - I tried @var - it didn't work. Now it works great.

Comment: If you always define array in the same way and pass it to the object then answer is yes. You can create custom plugin for the completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to PhpStorm to autocomplete unknown properties?

Yes and No -- it depends on how you plan to use it.

---

If you want to have it absolute dynamic (e.g. the same `Fields` class but in one file `$fields` variable (instance of that `Fields` class) will have one set of fields and in another completely different) -- then answer is No.

---

Otherwise it's possible to declare non-existing property via **`@property`** tag ([see detailed link](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#714-property)) in PHPDoc comment for that class.

```php
/**
 * @property string $abc Optional description here
 */
class Fields {
...
```

Now every instance of `Fields` will have `abc` property offered in completion.

With that in mind you can have all actual code/logic in `Fields` class and then declare specific fields in child classes:

```php
/**
 * @property string $first
 */
class FirstClassFields extends Fields {
...
}

/**
 * @property string $second
 */
class SecondClassFields extends Fields {
...
}
```